# Upload local self-signed certificate to Entra Id application Python

Tags: python, azure-sdk, azure-app-registration

With [Create a self-signed public certificate to authenticate your application | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-self-signed-certificate#create-and-export-your-public-certificate) created certificate.

```
$certname = "{certificateName}"    ## Replace {certificateName}
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256

Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\$certname.cer"   ## Specify your preferred location
```

Any way to add this certificate to Entra Id app registration programatically using Python SDK?

[enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/TPY5JnL.png)

Comment: Why don't you upload it via Powershell as well? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate?tabs=azure-powershell#import-a-certificate-to-your-key-vault

Comment: yes, @Zayn Lauren is that okay to provide a solution via PowerShell ?

Comment: @Imran powershell is not suited for my requirement atleast help me with graph requests if existed

Answer (score 1):

**To upload certificate to the Azure AD application, you can try the below:**

Generate the thumbprint and read the certificate key:

```
Get-PfxCertificate -Filepath "C:\Users\imran\Downloads\exchagecer.cer" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\imran\Downloads\exchagecer.cer.thumbprint.txt"

[convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content C:\Users\imran\Downloads\exchagecer.cer -Encoding byte))  | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\imran\Downloads\exchagecer.key.txt"
```

[image]

[image]

And use the below Microsoft Graph API query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ObjectID

{
"keyCredentials": [
{
"endDateTime": "2024-01-11T15:31:26Z",
"startDateTime": "2023-11-20T15:31:26Z",
"type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
"usage": "Verify",
"key": AboveKey",
"displayName": "CN=20230112"
}
]
}
```

[image]

***The certificate uploaded successfully like below:***

[image]

**To do the same in Python, make use of below code:**

```py
graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)

request_body = Application(
    key_credentials = [
        KeyCredential(
            end_date_time = "2024-01-11T15:31:26Z",
            start_date_time = "2023-11-20T15:31:26Z",
            type = "AsymmetricX509Cert",
            usage = "Verify",
            key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode("CertificateKey"),
            display_name = "CN=20230112",
        ),
    ],
)

result = await graph_client.applications.by_application_id('application-id').patch(request_body)
```

**Reference:**

[Add a certificate to an app or service principal using Microsoft Graph - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/applications-how-to-add-certificate?tabs=http)